Diagonal Cracks in drywall at corner of 1 piece shower/tub - Serious?
I am looking at a condo for sale.  In the guest bath, the 1 piece tub/shower enclosure has diagonal drywall cracks extending from the left upper edge/corner (on the showerhead side) and the right upper edge/corner (opposite side).  The left side is about 6" long and the right side is about 3" long - they are probably less than 1mm wide.  What could be causing this?  Could this be caused by improperly installed enclosure?  Is this something serious?  Property is 2008 build, ground floor of 2 story building.  The seller is aware of the cracks but not aware of any issues (90+ year old lady).
Thanks for your help!


This looks like a surface crack probably caused by tightening the shower curtain rod too tight. A taping job and light mud can crack with a concentrated pressure point like those shower rods cause if tightened too much. I've caused cracks with those stupid rods and replaced them with screw in rods.
If the seller has some leftover paint, use a hairline brush and you'll cover that right up.

Also, if you can stand the look aesthetically, a round metal plate would help distribute the force from the tension (really, compression) rod better.
